# MS SharePoint Search API doesn't return all files

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I'm using the MS SharePoint Search API over Rest to get the file paths to all PDF files on a SharePoint site. I use the Search API iterative, because there are more than 5000 file on the site.

What I'm doing is:

```
https://[root_url]/_api/search/query?QueryText='*+site:"[root_url]/[listname]"'
&RowLimit=500&RowsPerPage=500&StartRow=0&Refiners='fileType'
&RefinementFilters='fileType:pdf'&TrimDuplicates=false
```

...until the list is empty.

The listname contain a whitespace.The query works, it returns 2661 files. TrimDuplicates does its job somehow. Without TrimDuplicates, the query returns only 1169 files.

Some of the missing files are duplicates. They are at different places with the same name and content. But some files are missing at all.

I can download the missing files via:

```
https://[root_url]/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('[path]')/Files('[filename]')/$value
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [search query tool](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Solutions/SharePoint.Search.QueryTool) to query the missing document (e.g. by title or path) and compare the managed properties with your filters in the query. If you cannot get the file via search query at all, please ensure that the list is not excluded from search index and a crawl indexed the document.

Comment: I tried to find one of the documents explicit and couldn't get the document with the search query at all. It isn't related to the list, only some files.
I'm also not able to find the file trough the SharePoint website. So there seems to be a problem with the search index.